# File read after call to system()

Tags: c++, file, system

My C++ program calls another program via `system()`.  That program writes out to a file.  I can't modify the called program.

My program then needs to read in the file that was written.  At the present, my program reads in the file so quickly that the changes by the other program haven't yet hit the file system, and my program reads in an outdated version.

How can I force the called program to finish writing before my program tries to read?  Or perhaps how can the calling program check that the file is finished being written?

I switched to `system()` from `fork/execv` and CreateProcess specifically so the program would block and I wouldn't have to watch for termination.  So, I could switch back if that would help.

Right now, my only idea would be to delete the file before calling `system()` -- that way it wouldn't exist unless writing had completed.

Any solution needs to have versions for Mac, Windows, and Linux.

Comment: Don't use `system()`. It's evil.

Comment: Does your system() call your program directly?  Does the program do its task in the same process (vs. spawn a detached process etc)?  system() blocks until the subprocess exits; any file updates made by it should be visible to parent.

Comment: My system() call does call the program directly -- the program does nothing fancy.  Just a single process that writes a simple text file and exits.  I agree that any changes should be visible -- that is why I used system() -- but it doesn't work.  If I wait a short while and open it, I get the desired behavior.

Comment: Qix, I'm sorry you feel that a standard API call could be evil.  Switching from system to fork/exec and CreateProcess is an option, but it wouldn't solve this problem.  I had a wait() loop that monitored the process for completion and then read the file.  It sometimes worked, but sometimes did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use wait() method to implement this. wait method make the parent process wait and sleeps it until its child process finishes. you should use fork() and then exec the another copy of process generated.

Comment: fork/exec apply to linux and os x, but not windows.

Comment: you can use system in windows. which waits for the child process to finish

Comment: system() in windows, yes, but not fork/exec.  Windows has a completely different process creation model; not based upon cloning the parent.

Comment: but in windows system blocks till subprocess exits

Comment: fork/exec/CreateProcess vs. system() is irrelevant to my question.  I am aware of the differences, use both at different times in my program, and had this problem with fork/exec before trying system().

Comment: Accepting this as the highly unsatisfying answer.  Adding a wait() is the only thing I've found that works.  I'm worried about its robustness, but I'll deal with that when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know if you try to open the file not in reading mode but in writing mode it will fail if the file is already being written by another process.

I would suggest to have a small (a few milliseconds) wait time to make sure the file was opened by the other process and then try to write on it and when you can actually write on the file then you can read it.

I'm not sure how things work on Mac but I assume it would be the same as Linux and Windows here.

It would be much better to use `fork` and `exec` instead of system so my suggestion is just a simple way (but not recommended for an important project) to go around the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I'll try adding a wait() loop that opens the file for writing to detect this...  If that works, it should work for the fork/exec approach just as well as the system() approach.  I'll let you know how it works.

Comment: I assume that even when using the fork/exec approach the OS might take some time to close the file so it still could be useful to put that wait loop.

Comment: Well, the fopen(fname,"w") always succeeds, program execution flies right by, and the old version of the file is loaded.  The program works with a usleep(10000), but fails without it.  No loop needed, just sleep once.  I don't mind the wait per-say, but it feels really fragile.  How much of a delay is enough?  What happens when computers are faster? etc.

Comment: IS your other program locking the file for writing or not? Many programs tend to read the file to memory and then close it so they don't lock it. I assume it is what happens here. In this case you can only check if there was a modification on the file but this is OS-specific.

Comment: Making a delay is a way to go around the problem and unless your computer is very slow (or has a problem with I/O) you can probably be safe with a timer, it shouldn't break on a faster computer because the sleep will be as long but the program will execute faster.

Comment: The called program does this: FILE *fp=fopen(fname,"w"); fprintf(fp,"blah"); fflush(fp); fclose(fp); exit(1);